# PHP boolean expression behavior between int and string

Tags: php, double, boolean, expression, equals

I'm having trouble grasping why the following two boolean expressions return different outcomes.

```
(0 == "some_string") returns TRUE
(0 === "some_string") returns FALSE
```

I understand that the second expression returns `FALSE` due to the fact that 0 and "some_string" aren't of the same type, but I don't understand why the first one returns TRUE. PHP evaluates 0 as FALSE and a non empty string as TRUE, and 0 isn't the same as "some_string". I just don't see how the first expression evaluates the way it does. Is there a fundamental concept that I am missing?

Comment: you might want to read this manual section: http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 2):

That's because it casts `"some_string"` to `int` in order to compare it with `0`. `"some_string"` as `int` is `0` and `0 == 0` is `true`. Take a look at the manual page about [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) for more about this.